# Mechanism of reaction of ketones with isoalkanes under conc. sulfuric acid and heat

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, elimination

Taken from the book of GOC by Dr. O.P Tandon, Himanshu Pandey, Dr. A.K. Virmani,

[image: isobutane reacts with acetone under concentrated sulfuric acid and hear to form 2,3,3-trimethyl-2-butanol]

Can anyone elaborate on the mechanism?

Comment: Conversion of alkanes to alkenes using conc. H2SO4 and heating, where have you seen this? Do you mean alcohols?

Comment: @Ashish Ahuja my mistake. I edited it out

Comment: It seems like an interesting reaction, if it is correct; I've never seen alkanes reacting in such a manner. But surely acetone should undergo acid-catalysed aldol, it seems weird that the book has not mentioned that at all.

Comment: This isn't acid catalyzed aldol, for that you need two carbonyl compounds. Isobutane is not a carbonyl compound.

Comment: In which section/context/chapter/topic is this reaction given in the book?

Comment: @TRC uhh acetone can undergo self-aldol?

Comment: @TRC Under "saturated aliphatic hydrocarbons"

Comment: @AshishAhuja Oh yes, of course it can. I meant that the final product depicted here certainly isn't acetone's self-aldol product, rather it looks like a sort of condensation between the two compounds.

Comment: Due to lack of much complexity there is only really 1 plausible way to look at this, you have to generate a nucleophile to make any headway. This acidic media makes it impossible to do that. $\ce{H2SO4}$'s most extreme reaction is charring action (It never generates nucleophiles anyway). I don't see anyway to facilitate any further reaction. Self aldol looks way more plausible.

Comment: This https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01156a075 and this https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780471678656.ch12 may help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was going to be a comment but it got too long.

---

**TL;DR: - This is not an answer, rather a justification for why the question is (probably) wrong.**

This paper (linked by @Rishi) gives us experimental evidence that under action of concentrated $\ce{H2SO4}$ hydrogens are exchanged from paraffins in the following fashion:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{(CH3)2CHCH3 + 2H2SO4 -> (CH3)C^{+}OSO3H^{-} + SO2 + 2H2O   & \tag{R1}}\\
\ce{(CH3)3C+ + (CH3)3CH -> (CH3)3CH + (CH3)3C+ & \tag{R2}}\\
\end{align}
$$

R1 is the slow step and chain initiating step. R2 is the chain propagating step (the hydride transfer here creates a chain of approximately 20 tert-butyl carbocation.

Conc. $\ce{H2SO4}$ is a well known dehydrating and oxidising agent and tert-butyl carbocation has considerable stability due to extensive hyperconjugation. So it is possible that the reaction mechanism is of the following manner:

[image]

From the paper by Otvos et.al.<sup>1</sup>:

> Chains are terminated by some irreversible side reactions of carbonium
> ions leading to nonvolatile products. This picture would account for
> the lack of exchange between t-isobutane hydrogen atoms and sulfuric
> acid, since any molecule dissolving in acid, reacting and re-entering
> the vapor phase, would have received a new tertiary hydrogen from
> another isobutane molecule.

The chain termination step is where we run into a problem. Carbonyl group cannot act as a nucleophile at the carbon center. There is one way to do this but it is extremely unlikely

[image]

This is not a good mechanism due to the excess of $\ce{H^+}$ present. In fact, any mechanism for the given product wouldn't be satisfactory because any nucleophile produced at carbonyl carbon would be would be quickly protonated (tert-butyl carbocation can't compete with $\ce{H+}$ due to steric reasons). Also it is highly unlikely that $\ce{SO2}$ would participate in the reaction rather than escape to atmosphere (I suppose you can use sealed tubes).

Further problems are the much better suited side reactions such as acid-catalyzed aldol and attack of $\ce{C=O:}$ lone pair on the carbocation.

---

**Citation**

1. The Behavior of Isobutane in Concentrated Sulfuric Acid1
   J. W. Otvos, D. P. Stevenson, C. D. Wagner, and O. Beeck
   Journal of the American Chemical Society **1951** 73 (12), 5741-5746
   DOI: [10.1021/ja01156a075](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01156a075)

Comment: I fixed some punctuation and citation. Feel free to roll back if you don't like the edit. Tip regarding formatting: Instead of spamming `~`, use `\begin{align}`. It looks pleasant.